# How to use LSTM ? RecurrentPPO from sb3-contrib

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, stable-baselines

I'm working on creating an LSTM-based reinforcement learning model and trying to understand how Recurrent PPO from sb3-contrib works. Here's a simplified example of the code:

```
# import gym
# from gym import spaces
# import torch
# import numpy as np
# from sb3_contrib import RecurrentPPO

class env_LSTM(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, qnt_steps, qnt_features, qnt_actions, states_input):
        super(env_LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.states_input = states_input
        self.index_states_input = 0
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(qnt_steps, qnt_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(qnt_actions)
    def reset(self):
        self.index_states_input = 0
        return self.states_input[self.index_states_input]
    def step(self, action):
        self.index_states_input += 1
        done = self.index_states_input == len(self.states_input)-1
        return self.states_input[self.index_states_input], 0, done, {'a':1}
    
steps, features, actions = 10, 5, 3
    
states = torch.randn(20, steps, features)    
env = env_LSTM(steps,features,actions,states)    

model = RecurrentPPO('MlpLstmPolicy', env, verbose=1)
```

In this scenario, I'm creating an observation space with 10 time steps and 5 features. The states are randomly generated for demonstration purposes.

However, I'm having trouble understanding the architecture of the model. When I check model.policy, it returns:

```
model.policy
```

return:

```
    RecurrentActorCriticPolicy(
    (features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
        (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
    )
    (pi_features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
        (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
    )
    (vf_features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
        (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
    )
    (mlp_extractor): MlpExtractor(
        (policy_net): Sequential(
        (0): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=64, bias=True)
        (1): Tanh()
        (2): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=64, bias=True)
        (3): Tanh()
        )
        (value_net): Sequential(
        (0): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=64, bias=True)
        (1): Tanh()
        (2): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=64, bias=True)
        (3): Tanh()
        )
    )
    (action_net): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=3, bias=True)
    (value_net): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=1, bias=True)
    (lstm_actor): LSTM(50, 256)
    (lstm_critic): LSTM(50, 256)
    )
```

The LSTM layer has 50 input features, but it should be 5 according to the observation_space defined with shape=(10, 5). It seems to be multiplying 10 by 5 and considering 50 distinct features.

When I provide an input like torch.randn(10, 5) and pass it to model.predict(), the model generates a prediction normally, generating a tuple with an action and a prediction of future states I believe.

in this part:

```
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(qnt_steps, qnt_features), dtype=np.float64)
```

I tried using only the number of features in the observation_space:

```
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(qnt_features,), dtype=np.float64)
```

But when I pass an input torch.randn(10, 5) to the model, it considers 10 different states of 5 features each, and makes a prediction for each state, resulting in 10 actions.

I'm unsure about how this works. If anyone has insights, I'd appreciate an explanation.

Additionally, I'm encountering issue with stable-baselines, using PPO2 and MlpLstmPolicy. When I use model.learn on my dataset, it consumes all memory and freezes the notebook. I've tried reducing batch sizes to consume less memory, but it still hangs. I've looped through the dataset in the environment without any issues; the problem arises when using model.learn.

Thank you for your help!

I tried using only the number of features in the observation_space:

```
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(qnt_features,), dtype=np.float64)
```

But when I pass an input torch.randn(10, 5) to the model, it considers 10 different states of 5 features each, and makes a prediction for each state, resulting in 10 actions.